# How to test sending email in blackberry eclipse plugin 1.1

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Hi friends I usedthe code below for sending mail.
I tested it in JDE5.0 with ESS it doesnt work.
So please give me some solution.

import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.*;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.event.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
public class BasicMail extends Application {
private Store store;
static void main (String args[]) {
BasicMail app = new BasicMail("a");
app.enterEventDispatcher();
}
BasicMail(String s)
{
 //Get the Store from the default mail Session.
 Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();

//retrieve the sent folder
 Folder[] folders = store.list(Folder.SENT);
 Folder sentfolder = folders[0];

//create a new message and store it in the sent folder
 Message msg = new Message(sentfolder);
 Address recipients[] = new Address[1];

try {
      recipients[0]= new Address("poovavin@gmail.com", "poovannan");

```
  //add the recipient list to the message
  msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients);

  //set a subject for the message
  msg.setSubject("Test email");

  //sets the body of the message
  msg.setContent("This is a test email from my BlackBerry Wireless Handheld");

  //sets priority
  msg.setPriority(Message.Priority.HIGH);

  //send the message
  Transport.send(msg);
```

}
 catch (Exception me) {
      System.err.println(me);
 }
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

Visit this below link this will help you.

http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/sending-email-with-attachment-in.html